# Stored procedure - One Line select statement Syntax ERROR

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

One line select statement throws syntax error in SP, but the query if executed doesn't produce any error.

The error changes to `syntax error near -` if I remove `IN _HOSTID` input parameter and `DECLARE` statements. Its very weird and I can't find the cause of the error.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE getTotalCCU(IN _HOSTID INTEGER)
BEGIN
DECLARE HOSTID INT;
DECLARE TOTAL_ITEM INT;

SELECT  item_count  FROM items WHERE hostid = '12345' and key_ LIKE '%_net%' AND NOT key_  LIKE '%Total_%' AND NOT key_ LIKE '%{#%' AND STATUS = '0';

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Only when I try to import it, it throws syntax error on line 3.

```
mysql -uroot -p DB01 < getTotalNET.sql

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-



END' at line 12
```

Comment: The input parameter has to have a datatype (int,varchar etc)

Comment: Updated. The error now changed to `near -`.

Comment: If you are importing from a .sql script I don't think you need to set delimiters but why import don't you have a ui or at least command line sql?

Comment: it threw error without delimiter like syntax error, but the error happens only sometimes. Like I tested the sql file line by line and it got imported. Then when I had to update it, it started throwing error again, then I copied and pasted block by block and it got imported. I don't have a tool yet and working directly on linux cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

Variable should not be the same as any column in the query.

```
DECLARE HOSTID INT;

SELECT  item_count  FROM items WHERE hostid = '12345' and key_ LIKE '%_net%' AND NOT key_  LIKE '%Total_%' AND NOT key_ LIKE '%{#%' AND STATUS = '0';
```

Since the query has a column named `hostid` we get a syntax error.

Solution rename the `HOSTID` variable to `_HOSTID`.

```
DECLARE _HOSTID INT;
```