# MySQL cursor always exits out of loop

Tags: mysql, cursor

The cursor query and `select value` query returns rows if I run it in `mysql` but when in a cursor it always exits out of loop.

Anything wrong here?

I've added "BEFORE LOOP", "EXIT" and "IN LOOP" so it prints where it is but it always starts with `BEFORE LOOP` and then ends with `EXIT`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTotal()
BEGIN

DECLARE HOSTID INT;
DECLARE cITEMID INT;
DECLARE Total INT;
declare finished INT default false;
declare cur1 cursor for SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = 10579;
declare continue handler for not found set finished = true;

open cur1;
   loop_1: loop
        fetch cur1 into cITEMID;
        SELECT "BEFORE LOOP";
        if finished then
            SELECT "EXIT";
            leave loop_1;
        end if;
        SELECT "IN LOOP";
-- Test query
      SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = cITEMID ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1;

-- Final select query will look like this.
-- SET @Total := @Total + (SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = cITEMID ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1);
-- SELECT @Total;

  end loop;
close cur1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Queries:

```
SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = 10579;
| itemid |
| 12345  |
| 12346  |
| 12347  |

SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = 12345 ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1;
| value | 
| 1     |
```

Comment: Why do you use a cursor instead of just joining the tables?

Comment: `SELECT i.itemid, MAX(h.value) FROM items i JOIN history_uint h ON h.itemid = i.itemid WHERE i.hostid = 10579 GROUP BY i.itemid`

Comment: The main procedure I want to write will sum the values of returned by each row and store  it a variable and then outputs. Already tried joins and other stuff but the thing I want to achieved can't be done any other way unless it is looped each row and store them in a variable and sum them. I just wanted this part of the sp work so I can create the thing I need.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(value) FROM (<the above join>) x`

Comment: I'm not really that experienced with cursors, so I'm not sure.

Comment: okay. I know SUM function and all.. Have tried everything. I'm trying to implement something that's kinda not possible. But just need the SP to work

Comment: Are you really using `SELECT ... INTO variable` in your second `SELECT`? That will trigger the `not found` continue handler if it doesn't find anything.

Comment: nope. Right now it is exactly as it shows now. I tried `SELECT "something";` in the place of `SELECT value from history_uint` but that did not get executed at all. So I tried a select from history_uint and that has the same problem as well.

Comment: At least `SELECT "IN LOOP"` should run no matter what, but the sp leaves the loop before it gets there

Comment: Have you tried making `finished` an INT? MySql's [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) typically use INT, not `bool` (which is kind of not a real type in MySQL).

Comment: yea I tried INT as well

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

Variable should not be the same as any column in the query.

```
DECLARE HOSTID INT;

declare cur1 cursor for SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = 10579;
```

Since the `cur1` query has a column named `hostid` it will trigger the `not found` continue handler which sets `finished` variable to `true`.

Not only it triggers continue handler but in some cases it can produce syntax error. Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988686/13109839

Solution rename the `HOSTID` variable to `_HOSTID`.

```
DECLARE _HOSTID INT;
```